# Unauthorized response when requesting nearby stations

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to make a request to `/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json` but I keep getting a response with the message "These credentials do not authorize access." The full response is:

```
{
  "Res": {
    "serviceUrl": "https://cit.transit.api.here.com/transit/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json",
    "Message": {
      "code": "I4",
      "level": "E",
      "text": "These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer representative or submit a request here https://developer.here.com/contact-us to upgrade your account. You can also get valid credentials by registering for a free trial license on https://developer.here.com."
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Is this endpoint subject to accepting any further T&Cs? Or is it not included in the Public Basic Plan?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide your app id and app code in order to use the API. It is included the basic plan and you shouldn't have any problem accessing it.

```
https://transit.api.here.com/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json?center=55.7541%2C37.6200&radius=350&app_id={YOUR-APP-ID}&app_code={YOUR-APP-CODE}&max=3
```